# ListView, não repetir registros

Tags: delphi

Tenho 2 listview e um timer. Esse timer captura os registros que existem com um determinado comentário e coloca no outro listview. Acontece que ele está repetindo os registros, gostaria que ele adicionasse apenas uma vez o registro, e checasse, se já existir o registro no outro LISTVIEW, ele ignora. O que estou fazendo de errado ? Segue meu código:

```
 for I := 0 to Form1.LV1.Items.Count-1 do
      begin
      if Form1.LV1.Items[I].SubItems[5] = 'OK' then // confere se existe o comentário
      begin
      Form1.LV2.Visible := True;
      L := Form1.LV2.Items.Add;
      for J := 0 to Form1.LV2.Items.Count-1 do
      if Form1.LV2.Items[J].SubItems[5] <> Form1.LV1.Items[I].SubItems[5] then  // aqui tentei fazer não repetir (não deu certo).

      Form1.LV2.Items.item[Form1.LV2.Items.count-1] := Form1.LV1.items.item[i];
      end;
```

Alguma ideia ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como não sabia qual você queria, fiz as duas funções. Com relação à lógica, com a listview vazia você sempre adiciona, afinal, sem itens, não há repetições e a partir do segundo aplica a função que preferir

```delphi
function VerificaLVSubItem(Lista: TListView;Subitem:integer; Verifica:String):string;
var i : integer;
begin
  Result := '1';
  for i := 0 to lista.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if lista.Items[i].SubItems[subitem] = Verifica then
      Result := '';
  end;
end;

function VerificaLVItem(Lista: TListView;Verifica:String):string;
var i : integer;
begin
  Result := '1';
  for i := 0 to lista.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if lista.Items[i].Caption = Verifica then
      Result := '';
  end;
end;
```

E na chamada você coloca:

```delphi
  if lv2.Items.Count > 0 then
  begin
    if VerificaLVSubItem(LV2,1,'1') = '' then
      Showmessage('Tem')
    else
      Showmessage('Não Tem');
    if VerificaLVItem(LV2,'1') = '' then
      Showmessage('Tem')
    else
      Showmessage('Não Tem');
  end
  else
    Showmessage('Adiciona');
```

Comment: até deu certo em partes...qual o problema ? Ele precisa deixar adicionar o registro 1 vez, e começar a fazer esses testes a partir da segunda, pra ver se existe repetidos. Porque ? Porque senão já no primeiro registro ele vai ficar falando que existe, entendeu ? Pelo 1 vez eu preciso deixar adicionar pra depois testar se é repetido. Não sei se deu para entender.

Comment: Antes de adicionar você verifica, se não houver, no else você insere. Seria assim, primeiro verifica, não existe? Adiciona.

Comment: Eu tentei isso @filipe.fonseca, não sei porque não funciona, não sei se tem a ver pelo LISTVIEW estar em branco, digo o segundo listview antes de adicionar o ITEM, veja o código: http://pastebin.com/waNQhJqs

Comment: Dúvida rápida, @user7605 você está comparando itens com subitens?

Comment: boa pergunta, na verdade eu preciso comparar os 2 subitems, se for igual, ele não adiciona.

Comment: Então vou precisar alterar a rotina FindListViewItem pra verificar tudo. Assim que tiver um tempinho faço isso pra você.

Comment: é verdade @filipe.fonseca, a função está comparando um subitem a um item, nem tinha me ligado nisso!! Valeu amigo só falta isso para terminar o projeto.

Comment: até poderia ser comparar só os itens, não preciso comparar o subitem. Só preciso ver se aquele registro já existe ou não no outro listview. O que eu preciso mudar nesse caso ?

Comment: Você quer itens ou subitens?

Comment: subitems mesmo....altera muita coisa ?

Comment: Bom, fiz os dois, Dê uma olhada no edit, @user7605

Comment: Eu posso usar assim?  S := Form1.LV1.Items[i].SubItems[3];
          L4 := VerificaLVSubItem(Form1.LV2, 3, S);

Comment: deu certo, obrigado!!!

Comment: aproveitando sua bondade, tem um problema. Se existir 5 registros com a observação, ele não funciona, ele só verifica o primeiro e adiciona no outro listview, o resto ele não adiciona, porque será ?

Comment: Porque a função só busca um subitem, faça um laço for ou while e rode ela, assim vai buscar todos os subitens

Comment: eu fiz isso, veja, não está correto ? http://pastebin.com/qhRx5atm